# A simple contour plot consumes all the memory

Tags: plotting, graphics, memory

I ma trying to plot the following simple contour plot

```
Clear["Global`*"];
V = x^2*y^2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)];
f = 1/2*px^2 + V;
E0 = 0.12;
C0 = ContourPlot3D[f, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {px, -3, 3}, 
     Contours -> {E0}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 550]
```

However every time the program consumes very quickly all the available memory thus failing in producing the desired graph.

Any ideas why? Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: What if you set `MaxRecursion -> 0` and increase the `PlotPoints` setting?

Comment: Why 50 plot points?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kf4ST.png

Comment: @J.M. Now it works fine! But why for this case we should set `MaxRecursion -> 0`?

Comment: Just drop `PlotPoints`, I get a very decent picture without it, the same when set to `20` or `25` but much faster; `MaxRecursion` isn't required here.